# Extended classes synchronized methods locking

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Suppose this code

```
class A
{
    public synchronized void methodA()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    @Override
    public synchronized void methodA()
    {
        // ...
        super.methodA();
    }
}
```

What lock should be acquired by any thread if it wants to access methodA function of class B and methodA of super class A by `super.methodA()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `synchronized` method is equivalent to a method with its body wrapped in a `synchronized(this)` block. Thus, this:

```
public synchronized void methodA()
{
    // ...
}
```

is the same as:

```
public void methodA()
{
    synchronized(this) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, you can easily see that both `methodA` implementations lock on *the same object*, namely the `this` object. That is, if a thread is in a `synchronized` method of the *superclass*, it also prevents other threads from entering any `synchronized` method of the *subclass* (and vice versa).

Since `synchronized` locks are re-entrant, successfully entering `B.methodA` means that you can also immediately enter `super.methodA` (as you already have the lock).

Answer (score 3):

When you call `B b = new B(); b.methodA();` current thread will aquire lock on `b` , enter `B.methodA` and call `A.methodA`. Both methods share the same object and when entering `A.methodA` the thread will just re-enter the same lock which it already owns.